# Clean the JSON values but not the structure

Tags: javascript, json

I'm new to JavaScript, I want to have a JSON structure like this:

### JSON

```
{
    "ObjektId":["1","11","111","1111"],
    "Selected": [
        {
            "SelectedObjektId":"555",
            "SelectedObjektValues":["Test1","Test2","Test3"]
        },
        {
            "SelectedObjektId":"112555",
            "SelectedObjektvalues":["11Test1","22Test2","22Test3"]
        }//,and many others 
    ]
}
```

### JS

```
var json = new Object();
json.ObjektId = new Array("1", "11", "111", "1111");
json.Selected = new Array();
//console.log(JSON.stringify(json));
var util = new Object();
util.SelectedObjektId = "555";
util.SelectedObjektValues = new Array("Test1", "Test2", "Test3");

json.Selected.push(util);
//console.log(JSON.stringify(json));
util.SelectedObjektId = "112555";
util.SelectedObjektValues = new Array("11Test1", "22Test2", "22Test3");

json.Selected.push(util);
```

I have build this, but now my problem. I generate this dynamically by a function, the JSON-model is a global variable. Now when I call the function twice and so on, the JSON has the old and new values in. But I want only the new JSON values.
I have tried several things, but nothings worked.

```
function getJSONObjektList() {

    //HauptJSONknoten
    var jsonObjekt = {};
    jsonObjekt.ObjektId = [];
    jsonObjekt.Selected = [];
    //HilfsJSONknoten
    var utilJSONObjekt = {};
    utilJSONObjekt.SelectedObjektId;
    utilJSONObjekt.SelectedObjektWerte = [];

    doc = XYZ.GetCurrentDocument();
    doc.GetAllObjects(function (objects) {
        for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
            var obj = objects[i];
            var id = obj.id;
            var caption = obj.caption;
            var type = obj.type;
            var my = obj.my;
            console.log("[obj:" + obj + " id:" + id + " caption:" + caption + " type:" + type + " my: " + my + "]");

            //liste alle verfuegbaren  Objekte auf 
            jsonObjekt.ObjektId.push(id);

            if (type === "Statusbox") {
                doc.GetObject(id, function () {
                    var statusboxInhalt = this.Data.Rows;

                    for (var j = 0; j < statusboxInhalt.length; j++) {
                        var inhalt = statusboxInhalt[j];
                        console.log("Name: " + inhalt[0].text + " Wert: " + inhalt[2].text);

                        utilJSONObjekt.SelectedObjektId = inhalt[0].text;

                        var valAr = inhalt[2].text.split(",");
                        for (var k = 0; k < valAr.length; k++) {
                            utilJSONObjekt.SelectedObjektWerte.push($.trim(valAr[k]));
                        }
                        jsonObjekt.Selected.push(utilJSONObjekt);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
    $('#txtboxQv').append(JSON.stringify(jsonObjekt));
    return jsonObjekt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, objects are passed by reference. This means that your util object still references the one you pushed into your json object.

Basically, you need to create a new object.

Here's an updated version of your code, written a little more idiomatically:

```
var json = {};
json.ObjektId = ["1", "11", "111", "1111"];
json.Selected = [];
//console.log(JSON.stringify(json));

var util = {};
util.SelectedObjektId = "555";
util.SelectedObjektValues = ["Test1", "Test2", "Test3"];

json.Selected.push(util);
//console.log(JSON.stringify(json));

util = {}; // this is the key, you need to create a new Object
util.SelectedObjektId = "112555";
util.SelectedObjektValues = ["11Test1", "22Test2", "22Test3"];

json.Selected.push(util);
```

Guide to the syntax changes I made:

- [a, b, ...] - syntax sugar for new Array(a, b, ...);
- {} - syntax sugar for new Object();

This will produce the following JSON:

```
{
  "ObjektId": [
    "1",
    "11",
    "111",
    "1111"
  ],
  "Selected": [
    {
      "SelectedObjektId": "555",
      "SelectedObjektValues": [
        "Test1",
        "Test2",
        "Test3"
      ]
    },
    {
      "SelectedObjektId": "112555",
      "SelectedObjektValues": [
        "11Test1",
        "22Test2",
        "22Test3"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Update:**

This is my best guess as to what you expect:

```
function getJSONObjektList() {
    //HauptJSONknoten
    var jsonObjekt = {};
    jsonObjekt.ObjektId = [];
    jsonObjekt.Selected = [];
    //HilfsJSONknoten

    doc = XYZ.GetCurrentDocument();
    doc.GetAllObjects(function (objects) {
        for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
            var obj = objects[i];
            var id = obj.id;
            var caption = obj.caption;
            var type = obj.type;
            var my = obj.my;
            console.log("[obj:" + obj + " id:" + id + " caption:" + caption + " type:" + type + " my: " + my + "]");

            //liste alle verfuegbaren  Objekte auf 
            jsonObjekt.ObjektId.push(id);

            if (type === "Statusbox") {
                doc.GetObject(id, function () {
                    var statusboxInhalt = this.Data.Rows;
                    var utilJSONObjekt;

                    for (var j = 0; j < statusboxInhalt.length; j++) {
                        // make sure to re-initialize so we don't update the same reference
                        utilJSONObjekt = {};
                        utilJSONObjekt.SelectedObjektId;
                        utilJSONObjekt.SelectedObjektWerte = [];

                        var inhalt = statusboxInhalt[j];
                        console.log("Name: " + inhalt[0].text + " Wert: " + inhalt[2].text);

                        utilJSONObjekt.SelectedObjektId = inhalt[0].text;

                        var valAr = inhalt[2].text.split(",");
                        for (var k = 0; k < valAr.length; k++) {
                            utilJSONObjekt.SelectedObjektWerte.push($.trim(valAr[k]));
                        }
                        jsonObjekt.Selected.push(utilJSONObjekt);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
    $('#txtboxQv').append(JSON.stringify(jsonObjekt));
    return jsonObjekt;
}
```

**Edit:**

I just realized what your problem might be. From your comments, it seems that `doc.GetAllObjects` is an asynchronous call. This means that it will likely call the function after `jsonObjekt` is returned.

This isn't a problem if you don't use `jsonObjekt` until the function passed to `doc.GetAllObjects` returns, but that's likely not the case.

What you should do instead is have `getJSONObjektList` take a function as a paremeter and call it with your `jsonObjekt` when you're done populating it:

```
function getJSONObjektList(cb) {
    var jsonObjekt = {};

    ...

    doc = XYZ.GetCurrentDocument();
    doc.GetAllObjects(function (objects) {
        // this is likely getting called after the outer function exits

        // do your computation here
        for (...) {
            ...
        }

        $('#txtboxQv').append(JSON.stringify(jsonObjekt));
        cb(jsonObjekt);
    });

    // don't rely on jsonObjekt being populated here; GetAllObjects is probably async
}
```

You have another possibly asynchronous call inside as well (GetObject). I don't know the rest of your code, so I can't advise on how to handle when to consider jsonObjekt to be populated, but hopefully this gives you enough direction to approach the problem. You may very well need to rearchitect some things.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have change my code. But I have still problems: In my function I have declared it so.
function buildJSON() {
var jsonObjekt = {};
    jsonObjekt.ObjektId = [];
    jsonObjekt.Selected= [];
    //HilfsJSONknoten
    var utilJSONObjekt = {};
    utilJSONObjekt.SelectedObjektId;
    utilJSONObjekt.SelectedObjektValues = [];
//but in my method I have subfunctions like this

element.getIT(function() {

jsonObjekt.ObjektId.push(id)
});

when I make a return statement is my JSON object null

Comment: It's impossible to know without seeing more of your code (and it's terribly difficult to read code in comments). Maybe you could ask another question?

Comment: thanks for your tips, you can see my function in the edited question

Comment: Hi this look nice, I think you understand what I want to make, but my jsonObjekt is still empty on the return statement, what could be the error, I get some data from the function which I call

Comment: @Higune - it seems your problem is that GetObject and GetAllObjects are asynchronous. I gave an example for a single async call.

Comment: I call this on a click event on jQuery AJAX, could I get there a problem. I think the webservice method is calling earlier than the required function

Comment: I think it's because the functions (`GetAllObjects` and `GetObject`) are potentially asynchronous, which would make them execute after you return jsonObjekt. It's probably time to start a new question.

Comment: what must I declare in the cb function(), do you can give me some tips

Comment: My best tip is start a new question. Also, consider an async library: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249646/client-side-javascript-to-support-promises-futures-etc